# How do I use the keyboard to break into ruby-debug running a rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging

I'm running ruby-debug with `bundle exec rdebug script/server` on Rails 2.3. When I press `Ctrl-C`, it exits the entire program and the debugger. I want it to stop execution of the program and bring me into a debugger session.

I tried `catch Interrupt` but it didn't work. Is there an exception that gets called when I stop rails with `Ctrl-C` that would be good to use for this purpose? Or is there another way?

What I want is the equivalent of pressing the Break (pause) button in Visual Studio (I haven't yet done this with a Rails IDE).

Comment: And at what point do you plan on pressing that pause button? 
I doubt you are fast enough to catch rails inside one of your action methods.. You can use the `debugger` command in your code to create a breakpoint - but breaking like in VS with the pause button is pretty much useless in a Web-App

Comment: Hmm, maybe a dev-only rack middleware to call `debugger` (which I already knew about, thx) in response to a certain API call that I call with CURL, would be an adequate solution. But I'm planning to do it so I can use rdb's interface to set a breakpoint, so it doesn't have to be at a certain time. It just has to not stop the program.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I configure ruby to enter the debugger on Ctrl-C (SIGINT)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15278134/how-do-i-configure-ruby-to-enter-the-debugger-on-ctrl-c-sigint)

Comment: @Tigraine methods are often very slow if there's something wrong.  One common reason to break into a debugger is to find out why a method is taking a long time (often in library code).

Comment: in case you are actually looking for a performance problem in your code I'd recommend using a actual profiler instead of a debugger. Debugger is only useful if you know something isn't working and want to get in there and look at the scope to debug what's wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend [pry](http://banisterfiend.wordpress.com/2011/01/27/turning-irb-on-its-head-with-pry/) over ruby-debug.  Install the gem and then you can just stick this into your code where you want to debug:

```
binding.pry
```

Comment: Looks like you can start a pry session if you're using byebug (this was added to Rails long after this answer)

Answer (score 1):

you should just drop a `debugger` line in your code, this will automatically create a debugging session.