# Chef gets stuck editing /etc/sudoers

Tags: vagrant, chef-infra, chef-solo

I'm trying to deploy with `chef-solo` which is run by the `vagrant-aws` plugin for Vagrant. `vagrant-aws` is successful in launching an EC2 instances, rsyncing chef cookbooks and then starting a chef run. I'm using mostly stock cookbooks downloaded through the `librarian-chef` gem. There is one application-specific cookbook that configures the app's settings. The `sudo` cookbook is v2.7.0.

The issue is that every time I try to provision an instance, chef gets stuck editing `/etc/sudoers`. If I ssh into the instance, I find that the chef process is not running. It seems to exit without  any return code because `vagrant-aws` never finishes running either.

Here is the `--debug` output from `vagrant up production --provider=aws`:

```
==> production: [2014-08-21T02:02:46+00:00] INFO: template[/etc/sudoers] backed up to /var/chef/backup/etc/sudoers.chef-20140821020246.492236
DEBUG ssh: stdout: [2014-08-21T02:02:46+00:00] INFO: template[/etc/sudoers] updated file contents /etc/sudoers

 INFO interface: info: [2014-08-21T02:02:46+00:00] INFO: template[/etc/sudoers] updated file contents /etc/sudoers
 INFO interface: info: ==> production: [2014-08-21T02:02:46+00:00] INFO: template[/etc/sudoers] updated file contents /etc/sudoers
==> production: [2014-08-21T02:02:46+00:00] INFO: template[/etc/sudoers] updated file contents /etc/sudoers
DEBUG ssh: Sending SSH keep-alive...
```

Then it just repeats the last line over and over. After a while, the `chef-solo` process dies but without cleaning up `/var/chef/cache/chef-client-running.pid`.  If I run `chef-solo` again manually on the instance it finishes normally.

Comment: It looks like it is more hanging up after the sudoers change as the log state it has updated the file. What is the next resource in the runlist? you may also try to change the sudoers file adding a comment and run chef manually to see if it does the same thing)

Comment: Can you run with `log_level :debug` please?

Comment: @sethvargo I only encounter this problem when running chef through vagrant-aws. I already append `--debug` to the vagrant command. If I run chef manually on the server it runs fine.

Comment: It sounds like an AWS-specific issue then?

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling:

```
config.ssh.pty
```

option from your `Vagrantfile`. Usually it's the common reason for that kind of hangs.

In Vagrant docs for [config.ssh.pty](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/vagrantfile/ssh_settings.html) we can read that:

> This setting is an advanced feature that should not be enabled unless absolutely necessary. It breaks some other features of Vagrant, and is really only exposed for cases where it is absolutely necessary. If you can find a way to not use a pty, that is recommended instead.

As I had similar issue with [apt-get](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/6086).

---

#### Troubleshooting vagrant hangs

- on Unix/OS X you can press <kbd>Ctrl+T</kbd> to check the process state (why it's handing)
- run (install `lldb` if needed):

  ```
  echo "call (void)rb_backtrace()" | lldb -p $(pgrep -fn ruby)
  ```

  to print Ruby backtrace on the foreground (you can use `gdb` as well)
- perform logging, e.g.: `vagrant --debug up 2> frozen.log` and the working configuration to `works.log`, then compare with a diff tool
- on Unix/OS X run: `sudo dtruss -fn ruby` (or `vagrant`), on Linux use `strace`/`ltrace` to debug the process
- see: [Check why ruby script hangs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13406370/55075) for more suggestions