# Is there a way to use a keystroke to invoke the pry ruby gem?

Tags: ruby, pry

I was just thinking about how great it would be to be able to run a program and then hit a keystroke to invoke pry and debug. Maybe there is a gem out there that injects `binding.pry` dynamically during runtime that I don't know about. If there isn't, how would you make a keystroke that inserts `binding.pry` before the next line of ruby script that is about to execute?

Comment: How would that even happen? The input handler would have to - by necessity - be running in a separate thread from your "main" code in order to process input while the program is running. Have you looked at gdb?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming a POSIX OS, you could try adding a signal handler in your ruby program.  The ruby documentation even gives an example of your use case:

> .. your process may trap the USR1 signal and use it to toggle debugging (http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Signal.html)

```
Signal.trap('USR1') do
  binding.pry
end
```

Then, to send the signal:

```
kill -s SIGUSR1 [pid]
```

**Edit: A more complete example: application.rb**

My *naïve* suggestion above will fail with a `ThreadError: current thread not owner`.  Here's a better example using a global `$debug` flag.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'pry'

$debug = false
Signal.trap('USR1') do
  puts 'trapped USR1'
  $debug = true
end

class Application
  def run
    while true
      print '.'
      sleep 5
      binding.pry if $debug
    end
  end
end

Application.new.run
```

This seems to work best when application.rb is running in the foreground in one shell, and you send the SIGUSR1 signal from a separate shell.

Tested in Mac OS 10.9.5.  YMMV.

Comment: I'm getting `unsupported signal SIGUSR1 (ArgumentError)`. I am running Cygwin, though. It is supposed to at least be partially POSIX compliant. When I type `kill -l` at the prompt, `30) SIGUSR1` is an option. Also, I haven't been able to understand where to put this. I'm running a Cucumber test suite. I threw it in the `hooks.rb` file -- if that means anything to you! Thanks :)

Comment: Must be my setup... From `irb` I type `Signal.list`,  I got back `{"EXIT"=>0, "INT"=>2, "ILL"=>4, "ABRT"=>22, "FPE"=>8, "KILL"=>9, "SEGV"=>11, "TERM"=>15}`. So I've only got a subset of all of the POSIX signals.

Comment: For fun, see if you can co-opt one of the signals for your own purposes.  However, I don't recommend co-opting INT, TERM, or SEGV, and you probably can't co-opt KILL.

Comment: First update, I tried SIGINT. It actually did kinda work in that it popped me into a pry shell. It obviously terminated my process. Then i realized I wasn't running irb or cucumber from the cygwin shell. When i ran irb from cygwin all the signals were available. More tomorrow

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I was about to write that I thought there needed to be more to it! Now I'm thinking about how to run this with a cucumber suite.