# How do I configure ruby to enter the debugger on Ctrl-C (SIGINT)?

Tags: ruby, debugging, signals, sigint

I'd like to enter the debugger upon typing ctrl-C (or sending a SIGINT).  I have [installed the debugger](https://github.com/cldwalker/debugger) (I'm running Ruby 1.9.3) and verified that it works.  I've added this to my setup files (this is for Padrino, but I assume it would be similar for Rails):

```
# file: config/boot.rb
Padrino.before_load do
  trap("SIGINT") { debugger } if Padrino.env == :development
end
```

... but typing Ctrl-C does not invoke the debugger.  In fact, if I replace `debugger` with `puts "saw an interrupt!"`, typing Ctrl-C doesn't cause a print to happen either.

#### update

Following [this suggestion](http://programming-gone-awry.blogspot.com/2007/06/ruby-debug-ctrl-c.html) from [Mike Dunlavey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23771/mike-dunlavey), I tried explicitly calling `catch Interrupt` from within the debugger:

```
$ rdebug `which padrino` console
^Z^Z$HOME/usr/bin/padrino:9
require 'rubygems'
(rdb:1) catch Interrupt
Catch exception Interrupt.
(rdb:1) c
=> Loading development console (Padrino v.0.10.7)
=> Loading Application BlueDotAe
=> Loading Application Admin
irb(main):001:0>   C-c C-c^C
irb(main):001:0>
```

No joy -- interrupt did not enter the debugger.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to trap SIGINT while running in the console, the short answer is: you cannot unless you monkey-patch IRB.  Every Ruby app (whether padrino, or rails or whatnot) that uses the console will end up calling `usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb`, and in `IRB.start`, it does:

```
trap("SIGINT") do
  irb.signal_handle
end
```

... just before entering the main loop.  This will override any trap("SIGINT") you might have put in your startup code.

But if you want to trap SIGINT in a script file (for example, if you want to profile your code as described [by Mike Dunlavey here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4092705/558639)), you can create a script file such as:

```
# File: profile_complex_operation.rb
trap("SIGINT") { debugger }
MyApp.complex_operation
```

and then invoke it as in:

```
$ ruby profile_complex_operation.rb
```

Now, when you hit ^C (or send SIGINT from another process), it will enter the debugger.

Comment: Just a point of clarification - with this method when you enter the debugger do you enter the callstack at the point of the trap or at the point of code execution when you send the `SIGINT`?

Answer (score 1):

You may try to use [GDB wrapper for Ruby](http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2006/9/25/gdb-wrapper-for-ruby) ([GitHub](https://github.com/tmm1/gdb.rb)).

Install on Linux via:

```
sudo apt-get install gdb python-dev ncurses-dev ruby-rvm
gem install gdb.rb
```

Basic usage:

```
require 'gdb'

# create a new GDB::Ruby instance and attach it to
# pid 12345
gdb = GDB::Ruby.new(12345)

# print the (ruby) backtrace of the remote process
gdb.backtrace.each { |line| puts line }

# show the current local variables, and their values
p gdb.local_variables

# evaluate arbitrary ruby code in the remote process
p gdb.eval('%(pid #{$$})')

# show how many instances of each class exist in the
# remote process
p gdb.object_space

# raise an exception in the remote process
gdb.raise Exception, "go boom!"

# close the connection to the remote process
gdb.quit
```

Or to debug the hung process, attach it via:

```
rvmsudo gdb.rb PID
```

then:

```
# in gdb get a ruby stacktrace with file names and line numbers
# here I'm filtering by files that are actually in my app dir
(gdb) ruby eval caller.select{|l| l =~ /app\//}
```

Source: [Using gdb to inspect a hung ruby process](http://kueda.net/blog/2013/01/31/using-gdb-to-inspect-a-hung-ruby-process/)

Some alternatives:

- [rbtrace](https://github.com/tmm1/rbtrace) - like strace, but for ruby code (usage: `rbtrace -p <PID> --firehose`).
- [debug.rb](https://gist.github.com/tmm1/209839) script by tmm1 (author of gdb.rb) which can help to debug a process using strace/gdb.

See also:

- [Debugging Ruby Tools](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/debugging-ruby-tools/)
- [Check why ruby script hangs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13406370/55075)